# Is there a "right" way to abstract out my code?

Tags: c#, oop

I have been developing in C# for around 12 months now (from scratch, no previous dev experience apart from a little bit of PHP script hacking) and I like to think I have developed my skills to a level which I can write an app and it perform its function perfectly.

however, I am still a little confused about best coding practises,  I understand that this code is bad:

```
class Example1
{
    public static Alert GenerateAlert()
    {
        Alert AlertObject = new Alert();

        AlertObject.AlertDatetime = DateTime.Now;
        AlertObject.AlertHasRecords = false;

        return AlertObject;
    }
}
```

If for example `AlertDatetime` requires more than a simple line like `DateTime.Now;` I will end up bulking out a massive function. not good!

However, I cant see a problem with the following two examples (I favour Example 2)

```
class Example2
{
    public static Alert AlertObject = new Alert();

    public static Alert GenerateAlert()
    {
        PopulateAlertDate();
        CheckForAlertRecords();

        return AlertObject;
    }

    private static void CheckForAlertRecords()
    {
        AlertObject.AlertHasRecords = false;
    }

    private static void PopulateAlertDate()
    {
        AlertObject.AlertDatetime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}



class Example3
{
    public static Alert GenerateAlert()
    {
        Alert AlertObject = new Alert();

        AlertObject.AlertDatetime = PopulateAlertDate();
        AlertObject.AlertHasRecords = CheckForAlertRecords();

        return AlertObject;
    }

    private static bool CheckForAlertRecords()
    {
        return false;
    }

    private static DateTime PopulateAlertDate()
    {

        return DateTime.Now;
    }

}
```

Is one example better than the other, and if so why? or is there a completely different way of doing it?

Comment: The `Example3` is the way to go. No less, no more.
The `Example2` is bad in many ways unless you need singleton.

Answer (score 7):

**Your first example is fine.**

If, at a later time, `AlertDateTime` requires a more complex function to be initialized, you can always *refactor* your code to something like example 3. Until then, respect the KISS (Keep it simple) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principles.

Note that the *interface* (the publicly available methods and their signature) does not change between examples 1 and 3. This is a good thing. It means that you can move between those styles without having to modify the code that *uses* your class.

Example 2, however, has a lot of problems:

- The [information hiding principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) basically says that you should not expose something publicly without a good reason. Why would you store your newly generated Alert in a publicly accessible "global variable"?
- Example 2 *behaves* differently: If you call `GenerateAlert` twice, it will return a reference to the *same* Alert object both times. (Think about what happens if you call it once today and again tomorrow.)

As a side note, the naming of your methods in Example 3 can be improved. Try to think of each method in isolation: `PopulateAlertDate()` does *not* populate the alert date. It returns a date that can be *used* to populate an alert date. The name `GetDefaultAlertDate()` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @tornup Similarly, `CheckForAlertRecords` doesn't check _whether_ the alert has any records (you would return `Alert.AlertHasRecords` to indicate that, assuming the process of adding records sets this field to `true`).  In KISS-mode, I'd stick with Example 1 for now; if you came to refactor, the function from Example 2 (where you set the field to `false`) would probably the way to do it, but called something like `ResetAlertRecords` (and would/should probably remove any records an existing object already has).

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the great answer of Heinzi.

I'll add that in example 3 you are using a variation of the **Façade pattern**. You are wrapping a class with its complicated & repeated initializing logic, and also hide the interface of this object and expose new methods instead. If later you have several different ways to create the same object, you should consider the **Factory pattern**.

Pay attention: you should firstly favor placing some of the code in the original class' **constructor**, if there is no reason of using another variation at a time.

Example 2 resembles the **Singleton anti-pattern**, which serves another purpose - keeping one instance of a class. This is usually done for services you prefer being created once and for all. Even then, you better look at **Dependency Containers** for greater unit testing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If there's more logic in these functions than just assigning true or false, you might want to use a factory and interfaces. A completely abstracted code following the solid principles would look like:

```
public class AlertFactory : IAlertFactory {
     IAlertDatePopulator alertDatePopulator;
     IAlertRecordsChecker alertRecordsChecker;

     public AlertFactory(IAlertDatePopulator alertDatePopulator, IAlertRecordsChecker alertRecordsChecker) {
          this.alertDatePopulator= alertDatePopulator; 
          this.alertRecordsChecker = alertRecordsChecker;
     }

     public Alert GenerateAlert() {
          Alert alertObject = new Alert();

          alertObject.AlertDatetime = alertDatePopulator.Populate();
          alertObject.AlertHasRecords = alertRecordsChecker.Check();

          return alertObject;
     }
}
```

with

```
interface IAlertFactory { Alert GenerateAlert(); }
interface IAlertDatePopulator { DateTime Populate(); }
interface IAlertRecordsChecker { bool Check(); }
```

You can then add concrete implementations for these interfaces, for example:

```
public class DateTimeNowAlertDatePopulator : IAlertDatePopulator {
     public DateTime Populate() { return DateTime.Now; }
}

public class SomeCalculationAlertDatePopulator : IAlertDatePopulator {
     public DateTime Populate() { return /* something calculated */; }
}
```

resp.

```
public class AlwaysFalseAlertRecordsChecker : IAlertRecordsChecker {
     public bool Check() { return false; }
}

public class SomeCalculationAlertRecordsChecker : IAlertRecordsChecker {
     public bool Check() { return /* something calculated */; }
}
```

Then you can create configured factories:

```
public class DateNowAndRecordsFalseAlertFactory : AlertFactory {
    public DateNowAndRecordsFalseAlertFactory () 
    : base (new DateTimeNowAlertDatePopulator(), new AlwaysFalseAlertRecordsChecker()) { }
}
public class DateNowAndCalculatedRecordsAlertFactory : AlertFactory {
    public DateNowAndCalculatedRecordsAlertFactory () 
    : base (new SomeCalculationAlertDatePopulator(), new AlwaysFalseAlertRecordsChecker()) { }
}
```

And then just use your factory:

```
var alertFactory = new DateNowAndRecordsFalseAlertFactory ();
var myAlert1 = alertFactory.GenerateAlert(); 

var alertFactory2 = new DateNowAndCalculatedRecordsAlertFactory();
var myAlert2 = alertFactory2.GenerateAlert();
```

etc. This seems a lot of code for a simple functionality, but if you expect a lot of extensions with lots of logic coming up, then this is clean code following the open/close principle (to be open for extensions (by just adding new interface implementations) but closed for modifications (not needing to modify existing code anymore)).

Most effective when used with dependency injection. You'd then configure your factory like this:

```
public class DateNowAndRecordsFalseAlertFactory : AlertFactory {
    public DateNowAndRecordsFalseAlertFactory (DateTimeNowAlertDatePopulator alertDatePopulator, AlwaysFalseAlertRecordsChecker alertRecordsChecker) 
    : base (alertDatePopulator, alertRecordsChecker) { }
}
```

And just do:

```
var alertFactory = someDiContainer.Resolve<DateNowAndRecordsFalseAlertFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate an object and I don't see a point of having static method for that (there is an answer already with factory, do you really need that?)

In place where you have to create this object simply do

```
var alert = new Alert();
```

If you want to customize some of properties *after* object is created **with default values**, then here is shortcut

```
var anotherAlert = new Alert() { AlertDatetime = DateTime.Now };
```

Normally you should create instance of object in the way usable at most, so if you *always* have to construct it with current date, this is what constructor normally does:

```
public class Alert
{
    // do not add class name to property
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}

    // this don't need initialization if default value is false
    public bool HasRecords {get; set;}

     public Alert()
     {
         DateTime = DateTime.Now;
     }
}
```